# Upgrade SSIS 2008 R2 package to SSIS 2016 package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I need to upgrade my SSIS package developed in SQL Server 2008 R2 to Sql Server 2016 package. What is the easiest way to upgrade my package.dtsx file.

I am looking at an option where the upgrade happens on the file system. I would need to then open it using Visual studio 2015 editor and extend it further. The package should be compatible to run on SQL Server 2016 database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest upgrade method is just to open the file in VS 2015.

You will need to make sure the correct provider for OLEDB conns.

Also, watch out for script tasks. They don't always upgrade properly.

Comment: You mean VS 2015. Will that automatically upgrade

Comment: It will upgrade automatically.